# How to parse simple string in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I have a string with the following format:

```
start 123
```

I am parsing it that way:

```
if (strstr(line, "start") == line) {
    int number = -1;

    if (sscanf(line + strlen("start "), "%d", &number) == 1) {
        printf("start %d\n", number);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way in C?

Comment: You could write your own parser or try using `strtok()`. `sscanf()` is probably the best way though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes you can use only this:

```
if (sscanf(line, "start %d", &number ) == 1) {
```

no need for

```
if (strstr(line, "start") == line) {
```

any more

If you want to check more: Check that there is no extra characters after the number , then you can use the following format:

```
char c;
if (sscanf(line, "start %d%c", &number,  &c) == 1) {
```

**Note:** the above formats (and even yours) do not check that there is only 1 space between "start" and the number. so if your string is something like `"start \t 45"` then the `if` will return true

Comment: @Петр Широков note that this format do not check that there is only 1 space between "start" and the number.

Comment: That is ok. In my case the number of spaces does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strstr(line, "start") == line) {
    int number = -1;

    if (sscanf(line, "%*s %d", &number) == 1) {
        printf("start %d\n", number);
    }
}
```